# Selenium vs Puppeteer to test the UI of a CEF application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, integration-testing, puppeteer, chromium-embedded

I am planning to build integration test for my CEF application. The integration test will focus on verifying the UI of the app. I think there might be two ways to do it:

```
1. Use Selenium/webdriver + chromedriver: Selenium talks to chromedriver through
   webdriver protocol, and chromedriver talks to my CEF application through
   Chrome Devtools Protocol

2. Use Puppeteer or similar library that talks to CEF application directly
   through Chrome Devtools Protocol
```

First of all, is there a way for Puppeteer to connect to a remote chrome debugger? Most of the use cases seems to be launching a headless chrome within Puppeteer which is not what I want.

If both options are doable, which option would you prefer? Puppeteer seems to have richer functionalities than Selenium for testing user-agent that implements Chrome Devtools Protocol. The cross-platform benefit from Selenium/webdriver seems irrelevant for testing CEF application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, is there a way for Puppeteer to connect to a remote chrome debugger?

Yes, there's a [puppeteer.connect](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.8.0&show=api-puppeteerconnectoptions) that allows connecting to already-running browser.

> If both options are doable, which option would you prefer?

Given that you're only interested in Chromium, I'd pick puppeteer. Puppeteer scripts generally don't require throwing in "sleep()" calls - instead, there are powerful primitives to await conditions, e.g. [page.waitForSelector](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.8.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options), [page.waitFoRequest](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.8.0&show=api-pagewaitforrequesturlorpredicate-options) e.t.c.

Comment: One drawback I found using Puppeteer is that the Chromium version of CEF is not updated with the Chromium version of Puppeteer. So I have to use older Puppeteer version. Not sure if it is a big deal or not (lose some advanced features or bug fix?). On the other side, seems like selenium can work with any version of ChromeDriver so I can choose the one that matches the Chromium version of CEF and still have the full and updated features of selenium.